# NextJS + React Router - partially SSR app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to make partially SSR web application and looking for best solution for that. I need SSR for SEO and that will only serve dynamically rendered products pages - this will be handled by NextJS.

Other part of the app is only for logged users and I don't want anybody not logged to accidentally display it (but only users data have to be secure, if anyone access by a hack those restricted pages without any user data that's ok) - for that part I've already implemented React Router with proper redirections and few routes (it's using Redux too).

Whole project was made with create-react-app. Is there a way to easily combine those two functionalities? Do I have to move everything from /src to /pages? Maybe best way would be to serve them independently and just redirect to one or another using Apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wonders about it - currently the best solution would be to **use NextJS for all of it**, cause Next provides a clean way to handle static pages, CSR and SSR alongside each other.

By the default all pages are **static** generated or pre-rendered with partial **CSR**, while using getServerSideProps method allows to handle **SSR**, without any extra configuration.